# Prove an infinite differentiability of integral and find it's limit

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and bounded function. $A = \{(x, y)|y > 0\}$ and $F: A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$F(x, y) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{yf(t)}{(x - t)^2 + y^2}dt$$

Prove that $F$ is infinitely differentiable on $A$ and show that $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0+}= f(x)$ for all $x$

Please, can you give me a hint or an example how to solve such tasks?

Comment: use the theorem of differentiability of parameter dependent Lebesgue integrable functions

Comment: @Masacroso Could you please remind me what is it about exactly?

Comment: take a look at the second theorem [here](https://landonkavlie.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/differentiating-under-the-integral-sign/)

Comment: @Masacroso If I understood correctly, I can find partial derivatives using this theorem, but I'm not sure what I can do next

Comment: there is a theorem that says that if the partial derivatives are continuous then the function is differentiable, and the derivative at a point of a function can be represented by the Jacobian matrix. In short: you only need to check that the function can be partially differentiated arbitrarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varphi(u)=\dfrac{1}{1+u^{2}}$, then $\varphi\in C^{\infty}$ with $\|\varphi\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}=\pi$, by letting $\varphi_{y}(u)=\dfrac{1}{y}\varphi\left(\dfrac{u}{y}\right)$, then $\|\varphi_{y}(x-\cdot)\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}=1$ for any $x$.

One observes that $F(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\varphi_{y}\ast f(x)$ and hence $F\in C^{\infty}$, for the proof of the fact about good properties of convolution may be found in many harmonic analysis books, **provided that $f$ has compact support, if not, things might not be that easy.**

Now I show that the convergence. Indeed, 
\begin{align*}
F(x,y)-f(x)&=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{yf(t)}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}}dt-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{yf(x)}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}}dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{y(f(t)-f(x))}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}}dt.
\end{align*}
Given $\epsilon>0$, since $f$ is continuous at $x$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(t)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for $|t-x|<\delta$, then 
\begin{align*}
&|F(x,y)-f(x)|\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{y|f(t)-f(x)|}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}}dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{|t-x|<\delta}\dfrac{y|f(t)-f(x)|}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}}dt+\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{|t-x|\geq\delta}\dfrac{y|f(t)-f(x)|}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}}dt\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{\pi}\cdot\epsilon\cdot\int_{|t-x|<\delta}\dfrac{y}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}}dt+\dfrac{1}{\pi}\cdot 2\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|\cdot\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{|t-x|\geq\delta}\dfrac{y}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}}dt\\
&\leq\epsilon+\dfrac{1}{\pi}\cdot 2\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|\cdot\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{|u|\geq\delta/y}\dfrac{1}{u^{2}+1}du.
\end{align*}
Note that $\varphi\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{|u|\geq\delta/y}\dfrac{1}{u^{2}+1}du\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
as $y\rightarrow 0^{+}$, so the term $|F(x,y)-f(x)|$ can be controlled by arbitrarily small, we are done.

Comment: Could you, please, explain why this convolution is continuous without using it as a fact? If it's possible to explain it for this special case. Because all proofs I've found require integrability of f(x) or smth else.

Comment: Somehow I have underestimated the difficulty that $F$ being $C^{\infty}$, you are right, mostly we deal with smooth compact support $f$, but in this case I need to be careful, I will check again.

Comment: Actually this is what we called the Poisson kernel. Anyway, at least this statement is true for integrable functions, I am doubt that if continuous and bounded functions are sufficient too. Sorry for failing to help at this subtle technical point.